# iPhone 7 Plus not getting notification beep

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, notifications, bug

I’ve been having this issue for quite a while now. I just suddenly noticed my iPhone 7 plus stopped giving me notification beeps despite all notification settings properly configured.

I’ve read through solutions found online and after trying all steps, it’s still the same. The better solution I have experienced so far is that it’ll give me notification beeps for few minutes (max 1hr) and then it stops giving notification beeps again. Please let me know if anyone is experiencing this or has experienced it and what solution did the person arrive at?

Right now my last hope is to restore factory settings but I’m still scared of losing apps and their data and at the end of the day, the issue won’t be resolved. I’ll be so glad if someone experienced can engage in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following general tips if you have not already:

- Fully shut the phone down (long press the side button and swipe to shut down) and open it back up.
- Make sure **Do Not Disturb** is off.
- Check the ringer on the side and turn it off/on, sometimes there are unusual glitches that cause them to silence notifications.

When you refer to beeps, are you talking about the audible "ding" noise that you hear out loud, or are you referring to the phone vibration? The audible "ding" may have to do with your volume settings or potentially could be a result of your environment, such as:

- The WiFi disconnects frequently or you don't have a solid internet connection for various periods of time at your home/wherever you use your phone (this can cause notifications to not load and you won't receive a notification)
- Driving (there is a setting which mutes/blocks notifications while driving, some people are unaware this exists).

If you have a problem with vibration,  go to **Accessibility** > **Touch** > Scroll down to **Vibration** and click this setting on/off/on to make sure it is working properly.

It is important to note that some newer iPhones give a quieter notification sound when it detects that the user is looking at the phone/currently using the phone (**Settings** > **Accessibility** > **FaceID & Attention** >  **Attention Aware Features**). This feature is not on iPhone 7 as far as I know, but it is important to know for users who have the FaceID feature on their iPhone and are experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: I’ve tried all the settings. I had to restore factory settings yesterday and everything worked fine until this moment and I’m not getting pop up notifications nor the ding sound. I want to believe iOS 15.5 is causing the bug. I noticed this issue started when I upgraded to iOS 15.5. It really sucks.

Comment: I would highly suggest contacting apple support (if you haven't already) about this issue since they will be able to remotely access your phone if you allow them to and will be able to better pinpoint a specific setting or solution for you. Also, which apps specifically are not working?

Comment: I have contacted them but they seem to be clueless about the problem I’m facing. All the apps are not working. It really sucks.‍♂️
I’m really tired at this point that I want to change this phone.